# Using earthed appliances and extension lead with unearthed (Sweden) socket

Tags: grounding

I live in an old building in Sweden and the sockets are unearthed. Two pronged EU type.

I want to plug in an extension lead (earthed) and to have 3-4 appliances running off the extension lead. The appliances would be 1) lamp, 2) phone charger 3) TV

Would this be ok/safe to use earthed extension lead and appliances through an unearthed socket? What are the risks? I don't want to frazzle the TV or myself!

Also in Sweden they sell earthed and unearthed extension leads, which would be most suitable in this instance?

Thanks very much for any help/answers!

EDIT:
Thanks very much for all useful and helpful answers! Much appreciated, really overwhelmed actually by the time taken to provide such comprehensive responses, testament to great community knowledge and helpfulness so thanks again. I will now only used double insulated devices in the unearthed socket and until I have an electrician swap it out to an earthed. Cheers!

Comment: Do your appliance documents stipulate that they must be earthed. If you have lost the documentation or cannot find it, you might be putting lives at risk if you use said appliances on an unearthed supply.

Comment: Are the plugs for those appliances the grounded type? If not, it is fine to use without grounding. If the plug for the device is grounded then it needs grounding.

Comment: If the body of you appliances is made of dielectric, you do not need the ground. But if you connect grounded detention cord to ungrounded receptacle, it will not have a ground.

Comment: Generally the earth ground for devices with SMPS is to suppress up to 250 uA of RF noise from leaking out to grid to prevent unwanted AM radio noise and is not a safety issue. But for TV connected to an outdoor antenna, grounding antenna and cable and TV reduces risk of lighting damage or shocks.  But for AC electric motor drills/tools that are metal case, it is to prevent shock from contamination leakage currents so earth bonding is a safety requirement.

Comment: For laptop chargers  it's a noise suppresion current on ground , and lightning discharge suppression so your metal laptop doesn't get zapped and you touching it.  So if you choose to run a safer extension cord on motor driven 3 pronged loads, only use earth bonded extension cords AND outlets wired to earth ground ( like from a stove or copper plumbing.  Otherwise moisture ,contamination (dust) and leakage pose a safety issue on those devices with metal

Comment: If all the devices you plug on to the extension cord are also two-prong non-earthed devices, then it makes no difference if the extension cord is earthed type but connected to unearthed socket. What kind of plugs those devices have? I would not recommend connecting any devices with earthed plug to non-earthed socket

Comment: You can add a GFCI in the circuit typically of what is used on hair dryers in motels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that at least your TV and phone charger are **double insulated** devices which **do not** require earthing.

Find one of these logos on the devices:

[image]

Usually TVs and phone chargers are **class II** devices (right logo with two squares) and that means the devices 1) do not have a lead with a earth connection 2) can be used **without an earth connection**.

Regarding your lamp: it could be that the lamp is partly made of metal and that could mean it is **not** class II and therefore might need earthing. However, if the lead on the lamp itself does not have an earth connection (and it is the lead that the lamp came with from the factory) then it is OK to not earth that lamp.

Regarding extension leads with/without earthing connections:

In an **unearthed** wall socket you should also use an **unearthed** extension lead.

In an **earthed** wall socket you should also use an **earthed** extension lead.

In such an earthed extension lead you can safely plug in Class II devices that are unearthed. There will be no earth connection but that's OK, the device doesn't need it.

So: don't let the extension cord change the presense of the grounding.

Answer (score 2):

Grounding for safety is much like using seat-belts for safety. They both protect you in case of an adverse event. However that adverse event may or may not come. Just as people may drive cars for years without seat-belts and not be killed, people have used devices that are meant to be grounded for safety for years without being killed. However, just as I would not intentionally drive a car without wearing a seat-belt, I would try to avoid using devices that were meant to be grounded without a ground.

Grounding wires protect you from electrical faults, such as mains voltage appearing on metal surfaces of an appliance.

> Would this be ok/safe to use earthed extension lead and appliances through an unearthed socket?

To be honest, I might do so for a short period if I needed to use a new appliance and had the intention of correcting the situation soon. Perhaps not the wisest choice on my part. I am just being honest. I would definitely be cautious when first using it though. Some devices may have faults in them directly from the manufacturer. People on this site have reported being shocked by brand-new stoves which were not properly grounded.

> Also in Sweden they sell earthed and unearthed extension leads, which would be most suitable in this instance?

Since I strongly recommend that you do not use devices that are meant to be grounded without a ground *in the long term*, I would buy the grounded cable. You will be using the ground when you remedy the situation, right? The ground will not protect you *now*, but you do intend to fix the situation soon don't you? If you do not have that intention, then you should not use these devices ungrounded at all.

Answer (score 2):

Appliances which have protective earth in their mains AC power plug have it generally for good reason.

Reason1: The device doesn't fulfill insulation requirements which allow using them as unearthed in an environment where one can touch simultaneously metal parts of the device and something like concrete, waterpipe, electric heater, cable of outdoor antenna or simply another appliance which is properly earthed. The earthing shorts touchable leaks caused by faults to the ground and prevent electric shock.

Reason1 was understood well in 1950's but the code allowed unearthed sockets and devices in dry ground-free rooms. Things evolved and reason 2 became apparent say 40 years ago:

Reason2; Computers and other complex devices (like a modern TV) would be effective radio noise transmitters especially to the AC power input line if some countermeasures weren't done. The strongest radio polluter in devices is the switch mode power supply, but the computer circuitry has a good second rank.

One of the countermeasures is to have a metal shield which is connected to the protective earth wire. It must be accompanied by a properly designed radio frequency signal killing filter (=EMI filter) in the AC power input.

Unfortunately to make the filter to do its job well it must have some capacitors between the actual AC input wires and the protective earth. The protective earth is connected also to the low voltage circuit ground in the device. If you use that device with unearthed AC input, the device has half of the mains AC voltage connected to the metal parts and the low voltage circuit ground of the computer. It comes through the filter capacitors. They prevent a humans killing shock, but pass through enough to feel very unpleasant if you happen to touch at the same time some other objects which have some connection to the ground.

The shock may be too weak to kill humans, but I have met several cases when it killed another electronic device when interconnection cables were inserted.

Old houses were built with unearthed sockets in the era when their problems today were not predicted. You may need to let a proper electrician to make a properly earthed socket to you. Do NOT try it by yourself, use a certified contractor to avoid becoming a criminal.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule when connecting plugs is: if it fits, it is OK. You can use grounded plugs in ungrouded outlets. The opposite is not possible (excluding modern double insulated devices).

The principle of grounding in Europe (before it became universally required) was based on the
location, not on the equipment. In dangerous locations equipment had to be grounded. Dangerous locations are those that have water pipes or a conductive floor. Also the very act of putting a grounded socket makes the room dangerous as it introduces ground potential to the room. As would drawing an extension cord from the kitchen to the living room. This is why old ungrounded plugs do not fit grounded sockets.

As mentioned those equipment were all double insulated so the type of the socket or extension cord is irrelevant. However, if one uses equipment with schuko plugs there are some things to consider. If one uses a grounded extension cord on an ungrounded socket and if the case of any of them gets the mains voltage all get it. On the other hand the grounded cord levels the potentials between the equipment and can prevent equipment damage when connecting them (you should do that powered down though)

I personally recommend a portable RCD if one uses grounded equipment on ungrounded sockets. Also it is good to set them so that the radiator is not nearby. The radiator was at least in Finland an ugly compromise. A water radiator is grounded so every room should in theory be considered dangerous but that would have caused other problems so it was seen that the paint offered adequate insulation. If the radiator is electric it is grounded if and only if the sockets are grounded.

The current that a PC passes to the ground is about 0.5 mA. If it was higher, at dangerous levels, it would trip the RCD in modern homes - especially in the US where the triggering current is just 5 mA. However,you should not test it by feeling as you should not touch an ungrounded device and ground at the same time.